# In SharePoint list, how to add a table like excel where you can fill up information as you want?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, modern-experience, administration

like add a mini excel table into the list because columns are limited for entering more information

is there some coding that can make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, you can use the Grid view (quick edit) or datasheet view to bulk edit multiple items.

You can switch to grid view from normal list view using:

[image]

**Grid view in action**:

[image]

---

If you want to enter lengthy content in SharePoint list columns, you can create the **multiple lines of text** columns in the list:

[image]

You can either use "plain" multiple lines of text column for simple text or "rich" multiple lines of text column for adding bold/italic text, bulleted lists, hyperlinks, etc.

---

**Update from comments**:

If you want add a table inside a single "column" value, use multiple lines of text - rich text column in the classic experience list forms:

[image]

If you are using modern experience list, you can switch to classic experience list & list forms by following these steps:

- Go to your SharePoint list
- Click on Settings (gear) icon from top right corner and select **List settings**
- Select **Advanced settings** from list settings page and scroll at the bottom of advanced settings page
- Set List experience to **Classic experience** and click OK to save the changes:

[image]

**Microsoft documentations**:

1. [Create a column in a list or library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/create-a-column-in-a-list-or-library-2b0361ae-1bd3-41a3-8329-269e5f81cfa2)
2. [SharePoint list and library column types and options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/list-and-library-column-types-and-options-0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7)

Comment: I see but what it's not exactly a table right? Id still like it to be by column

Comment: If you want a table inside a "column", use multiple lines of text - rich text column in the classic experience list forms.

Comment: Check updated answer for more information.

Comment: many thanks! this works, is it possible to have a default table/values everytime new items are created?

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Unfortunately, No. You cannot have default table values for rich text columns in SharePoint.

Comment: Please [accept my above response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.